# Arrange an array based on sorting re-arrangement of another

Tags: python, sorting

I have two arrays `names` and `scores`. Every index in `names` correspond to an index in `scores`. How do I arrange `names` in the order that corresponds to sorted `scores`?

E.g from

```
names = ["Jo", "Mary", "Luke"]
scores = [9, 4, 8]
```

we get

```
scores = [4, 8, 9]
names = ["Mary", "Luke", "Jo"]
```

I have only one ugly idea is to first convert 2 arrays into array of tuples and then use standard python sort and then convert back into two arrays.
Are there any nice way without ugly for loops and double conversion?

Thanks

Comment: The duplicate I used is for nested lists (somewhat like a 2D array), but the principle is the same.  The answers below summarize the usage well enough for your 1-D case.

Comment: @Prune I believe the vectorized numpy solution is a good addition to the question and is not in the linked dupe

Comment: Agreed; voting to reopen.  I saw the `argsort` solution while I was looking for dupes, but don't find it now.  If it's not trivial to find, let's make this another reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

```
names[np.argsort(scores)]
```

assuming `names` is a numpy array. If not, just make it

```
names = np.array(names)
```

Comment: `numpy` is definitely an improvement over base Python for certain manipulations (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Could use:

```
[name for score,name in sorted(zip(scores,names))]
```

Logically, this is similar to the double-conversion approach you describe, but the use of `zip` and comprehensions achieves it in one line with no explicit looping.